# Is there any indication why Coruscant is no longer the center of the republic?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Is there any indication why the old capital of the Republic is not the capital of the New Republic?

(at least in the film I saw nothing there so I hope that the novelization has something there?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

*Visual Dictionary* says it's because it was, to put it short, more democratic.

> "To demonstrate that the New Republic was not doomed to repeat the errors of the past, one of Chancellor Mon Mothma's first edits was the restoration of the Galactic Senate, to create a forum where the Republic would define its very nature. It was decided that all worlds would have an equal say in the shaping of government. **This change resulted in the campital of galactic politics moving from Coruscant, its home for millennia. Member worlds would now host the Senate on a rotating basis. At this time, it is the cosmopolitan world of Hosnian Prime where the Senate convenes**."
>   *("Hosnian Prime" insert on the "Peace Interrupted" page with Galactic map)*

This tradition started right after the fall of the Empire. In Wendig's *"Aftermath"* book, we see the Senate convening on Chandrila (it was partly chosen because Mon Mothma was from there, presumably, but as we can see, rotated further):

> “Oh!” Olia says, thrusting up a finger. “You’re going to get a shot of what’s behind us, right? **Hanna City reflects the Senate’s humble new beginnings—we’re here for the people of the galaxy, all the hardworking people. And Mon Mothma is from here**, so—”

Just for completeness, the novelization does NOT address the reason.

Comment: uhm what? (sry I think I'm not getting what you mean? Was there a vote and taht was how coruscant was no longer teh seat?

Comment: @Thomas - see the canon quote in the update

Comment: Tnx dvk that is better at explaining it. Sounds almost like what the EU (Real life EU I mean NOT extended universe....thus the european EU) does use there.

Comment: Because I started sneezing after clicking on the accept button and didnt manage to get something to clean my nose until now :P

Comment: @Thomas - the sad part is that this excuse is far better than most in-universe excuses Abrams and Disney came up with :)

Comment: and it is even the truth :)

Comment: “Member worlds would now host the Senate on a rotating basis.” Oops. That backfired eh.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Well, I would say a decision to pass Demilitarization Act was far more of a blunder. After all, picking ANY world for the Senate would be irrelevant, First Order would know which one to blow up

Comment: They should have put the Senate on a starship, like Stasheff's DDT.  (For clarity, that's an in-universe "should".)

Comment: "Member worlds would now host the Senate on a rotating basis". Talk about scandalous. Just look at the IOC & FIFA.